# Redis and django

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models, redis

Redis seems to be a popular choice for caching in django, but is it also a viable option for using as a database for my django models as well. I'm considering moving a large category system from MySQL to Redis, lots of very small records (just name, parent_id, and id) so, though i'm fairly new to the idea of a key-value database, this seems to make a lot of sense?

The more I search around it doesn't look like there is an option to simply hookup a redis backend to django for syncing with Models?

Answer (score 3):

The official Django framework works only with RDBMS. 
In your case I would look into projects like [Django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel). They [blogged](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/redis-backend-for-django-nonrel-in-development) about Redis backend.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm late but it can help others.*

**Redis can be both**

1. As a Primary database
2. Cache

Django  officially  support  MYSQL and Postgres databases because it uses ORM (Object Relational Mapper).

So you can use MYSQL or Postgres as a Primary database and Redis for caching your most used models using Hashing in Redis.

Redis is basically in-memory key-value store if any failure occurred your data will be lost.

But Redis also support persistence you can check this.

[Redis persistence official doc](https://redis.io/topics/persistence)

---

**Recommendations**

I recommend use both MySQL/Postgres as primary database for Django to take advantages of ORM and Redis/memcached for caching.